# Building a fragment back stack

Tags: android-fragments

I am new to Android / programming and currently having trouble trying to get my app to direct the user straight to the second fragment in a tab with backwards navigation (hitting the back button should load the first fragment and not close the app).

My app consists of a single fragment activity and several tabs each with a container fragment and a few other nested fragments.  I've done this as I want each tab to have its own back stack.  Ordinarily (using my poorly constructed diagram below) if the user wanted to go to frag 2B they would select tab B, then frag 1B then frag 2B.

Tab A -> frag 1A -> frag 2A

Tab B -> frag 1B -> frag 2B

However when a new message notification is received I have a broadcast receiver in my fragment activity which displays an alert dialog asking if the user would like to view the new message.  Selecting 'Yes' should take the user straight to the message fragment (lets say frag 2B) from anywhere in the app (e.g. tab A, frag 2A).  I could add a fragment transaction when 'yes' is selected and whilst this will take the user straight to frag 2B, obviously frag 1B has not been added to the back stack so when the user hits the back button instead of seeing frag 1B the app closes.  I think it would also be the wrong place to put the transaction as my container fragment is where the nested fragment is created using getChildFragmentManager().

I have had trouble finding out anything about this, other than an Android article about creating an 'artificial' back stack with activities using the TaskStackBuilder [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#SynthesizeBackStack).  Whilst this does pretty much what I want to do it looks like it can only be used to build a back stack of activities and not fragments.

Can anyone point me in the right direction i.e. articles / tutorials on the web or from any experience of doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with this but a good place to get started would be to override the back button. This will allow you to have control over what happens when the user presses the back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
        if (on frag 2B && some condition) {
            //send user to frag 1B
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll have a look at implementing something like this in my code and let you know how I got on.